# Querying EventBusSubscriber via Salesforce API

Tags: rest-api, platform-event

I'm trying to query the [EventBusSubscriber[1]](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventbussubscriber.htm) via Salesforce API to a Connected App, it works like a charm from the developer workbench:

SELECT Position,Topic,type FROM EventBusSubscriber

However, when querying via the Salesforce API (same user as in Workbench), repeatedly getting the "sObject type EventBusSubscriber is not supported" message.  The documentation for EventBusSubscriber says: "EventBusSubscriber is read only and can only be queried. As of Summer ’20 and later, only your Salesforce org's internal users can access this object."

I guess this means I cannot access it via Salesforce API calls?  Does anyone know, if I were to create an Apex REST endpoint to query and return this information, if that would work, or if I would still get this error message?

Note I don't think this is a permissions issue, because, Salesforce does not appear to allow me to assign EventBusSubscriber to particular users via Profiles.  Indeed, the EventBusSubscriber object isn't even listed in the Object Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this in my org, it works fine. You can try it out yourself in "Your Name" (Classic) / ⚙ (Lightning) > Developer Console / Query Editor. Whatever API you're using, make sure you're using an API version that supports the object.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  Wasn't aware I was using a very old API version, never thought to update it.  Switched to V49.0 and API calls work fine now.